# Call functions one after another in Firebase

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I just wanted to know if the same Cloud Function is triggered many times, will its execution take place in the order it was triggered or will it be executed in parallel. If in parallel, is there any way to make its execution in the order of being triggered?